# load balancing with multiple ISP, one router and asa 5520

Tags: cisco, router, cisco-asa, wan, load-balancing

I connected different two ISPs to the RV340 with dual WAN support.

I want to connect the ISP - Router - ASA in the normal way, and connect the L2 Switch after the ASA.

- I need to know how to do DHCP Pool in ASA or Router.
- I want to route VLAN10 and VLAN30 to ISP1 and VLAN20 to ISP20.

[image]

Comment: and the purpose of using ASA is to use Site-to-Site VPN.

Comment: Do you need firewall filtering between vlans 10, 20 and 30?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I would not route the traffic through both the ASA and the RV340. Both devices have similar feature sets (in your scenario), and using both would be redundant. Since you already have dual-WAN setup on the RV340, and since you just want to use the ASA for VPN, then just put the ASA off to the side.
[image: suggested network drawing]
In the above drawing, the RV340 is the default gateway for all vlans (represented by colors). The ASA is on its own vlan, but it could be on a common vlan with something else, too. In your RV340, add a static route for the far-side of the VPN tunnel, pointing at the ASA.

For configuring DHCP on the RV340, scroll to page 55 of [Cisco's documentation](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/RV340/Administration/EN/b_RV340_AG.pdf) for the RV340.

Page 41 of the documentation talks about Policy-Based Routing, which is what you use to get certain vlans to use a certain ISP.

One final comment: if your ASA were newer, then you could do policy-based routing on it, also. In that case, I would not use the RV340 at all, and would do everything using the ASA only.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend placing the client’s gateway at the ASA.

For ASA 9.0 in example, Cisco has published a [manual](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa90/configuration/guide/asa_90_cli_config/basic_dhcp.html) on how to setup a DHCP server with the ASA. As you did not point out the version used, you need to look it up yourself. However, I do not think that there has been many changes in the way of doing DHCP.

To perform your WAN setup you need to enable Policy-based Routing on your RV340.
This is explained in the [manual](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/routers/csbr/RV340/Administration/EN/b_RV340_AG.pdf) delivered by Cisco. You basically need to tell it to send traffic from `192.168.10.0/24`and `192.168.30.0/24` via interface WAN0 and `192.168.20.0/20`via WAN1.